# unable to sum a particular column values with multiple distinct columns

Tags: mysql

```
Itemname    CostRate    Quantity
A               700     1
A       600     1
B       100     1
B       100     1
B       200     2
C       50      3
C       50      5   
C       50      1
C       600     3
D       100     1
D       250     3
```

I have a table called product and i have these columns itemname, costrate and quantity, i want to get the sum of the quantity which have distinct itemname and distinct costrate i try this query but its not working

SELECT sum(qtyset), distinct itemname, distinct costrate FROM product;

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this it?

```
select Itemname, CostRate, sum(Quantity)
from product
group by Itemname, CostRate
```